# Swift 4 CoreML wont get the first value of an array

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I'm trying to print out the first element of an array that comes from coreML? however it seems to just give out the full array.

```
guard let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }

guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: Inceptionv3().model) else { return }
let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (finishedReq, err) in
    guard let results = finishedReq.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] else { return }

    guard let firstObservation = results.first else { return }

    print(firstObservation.identifier, firstObservation.confidence)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.identifierLabel.text = "\(firstObservation.identifier) \(firstObservation.confidence * 100)"
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the output? This code looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide the output it would be easier to understand because code looks fine - it is supposed to print the first element.

Check one thing - maybe you are running the actual code snippet multiple times and the console output *looks like* you printed an array. To be more specific - you actually could initiate and execute your `request` over and over again, along with the model and everything there. Output then would look like:

```
request number 1 output first element
request number 2 output first element
request number 3 output first element
request number 4 output first element
```

in contrast to printing and array which would look like:

```
["request number 1 output first element", "request number 2 output first element", "request number 3 output first element", "request number 4 output first element"]
```

but that is just a guess, please post your console output.